# Looping Through a Nested List

Tags: tables, macros, loops

I have a hunk of data like so:

`{ { {AA},{AB}, ... {AZ} }, { {BA}, {BB}, ... {BZ} },
...
...
{ {ZA}, {ZB}, ... {ZZ} } }`

defined in a macro called `\clebschdata`.
Each term XX is a list of eleven numbers (e.g., {2,4,5,1,2,0,0,0,3,1,1}).
In other words, `\clebschdata` is a list of eleven things, each of which is a list of eleven things, each of which is a list of eleven numbers.

The data corresponds to a matrix that I'd like to put into a 12x12 table. I want the left column (in descending order) to look like `\bigotimes \chi_1 \chi_2 ... \chi_11` and the top row (from left to right) to be the same: `\bigotimes \chi_1 \chi_2 ... \chi_11`, where the `\bigotimes` in both correspond to the top left cell.

I have a macro defined `\chisum` that I would like to pass each entry of my data to before putting it into the remaining 11x11 table.

How do I loop through my list to meet these specs?

I have tried several looping macros from several different packages but I can't get any of them to work. In particular, I have the following thing:

```
\def\ttand{&}
\def\clebschtable#1{\hline\@for\tmpi:=#1\do{\chi\@for\tmpj:=\tmpi\do{\ttand$\chisum\tmpj$}}}

...

...

\begin{tabular}

\clebschtable{\clebschdata}

\end{tabular}
```

But it is giving me grief about an `! Undefined control sequence.` on `\tmpj`.

Edit:

```
\def\clebschdata {{{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}},{{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1}},{{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}},{{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,2},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,3,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,3}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,3,0},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,3,0},{0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,3}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,3},{0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,3},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,3,0}}}

\makeatletter
\def\thect{\value{ct}}
\newcounter{ct}
\def\chisum#1{\setcounter{ct}{0}\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\stepcounter{ct}\expandafter\zzz\tmp\relax}}
\def\zzz#1\relax{
    \ifnum #1=1
    \zzsep\chi_{\thect}
    \else
    \ifnum #1=0
    \else
    \zzsep#1\chi_{\thect}
    \fi
    \fi
}
\def\zzsep{\def\zzsep{\oplus}}
\makeatother
```

Also does anybody see what's wrong with the following?

```
\def\decompgirreps{{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0}, {1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0}, {0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1}, {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}}
\begin{tabular}{| c || c | }
    \hline $G^4$ Irreps & Decomp into $SL_2^7$ Irreps \\ \hline \hline
\setcounter{rowindex}{0}
\xintFor #1 in \decompgirreps \do {%
   \stepcounter{rowindex}
   $\mu_{\arabic{rowindex}}$ & $\chisum{#1}$%
   \\ \hline
}%
\end{tabular}
```

The part with `\chisum` is not working. When I remove the `\chisum` part and just keep it as `#1` then I see it is indeed looping through `\decompgirreps`, but there are no brackets around it. It seems like it is being expanded to `\chisum0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1` for instance when it should be `\chisum{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}`. There's probably a really simple fix for this...

Comment: Could you please give a typical `\clebschdata` macro replacement text, just to be able to play with it?

Comment: `\def\clebschdata{{{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}},{{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1}}}`

Comment: That's the first two rows of the full eleven

Comment: And then also:
`\def\thect{\value{ct}}
\def\ttand{&}
\newcounter{ct}
\def\chisum#1{\setcounter{ct}{0}\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\stepcounter{ct}\expandafter\zzz\tmp\relax}}
\def\zzz#1\relax{
 \ifnum #1=1
 \zzsep\chi_{\thect}
 \else
 \ifnum #1=0
 \else
 \zzsep#1\chi_{\thect}
 \fi
 \fi
}
\def\zzsep{\def\zzsep{\oplus}}`

Comment: Please, add to your question, where you can put the whole thing.

Comment: @egreg I don't understand your question.

Comment: not related to the `tex` aspects, but what kind of thing has its representations indexed by the `chi`'s?

Comment: if you add a complete `\clebschdata` and also what `\chisum` is supposed to do I could fill it in my answer and display the ensuing table so that you can check if it looks right. Are the `\chi`'s characters? representations?

Comment: @aentropy Add the definition of `\clebschdata` to the question; pasting it in a comment makes it partial and adds unwanted characters.

Comment: I've added `\clebschdata` and `\chisum`.

@jfbu: Yes ;-) We're looking at characters of irreducible representations of SL(2,7), the set of 2x2 matrices with determinant 1 over the field of 7 elements.

Comment: You have no hope to make such a big table with that data. Even at `\tiny` size it's 500pt over the margin, more than 17cm or a bit less than 7in.

Comment: I have now compiled the code with your data, modifying a bit the `\chisum` macro in passing. I will now look at your second question about why your code using `\xintFor` does not work.

Comment: For `\decompgirreps`, `\xintFor` is a tool which is sensitive to spaces, or better said the space does not disappear, and `#1` rather than being the comma separated list is a space token which `\chisum` could not digest. After removing the extra spaces after commas, the thing works, see my updated answer.

Comment: Please, don't pile up questions; the problem you added is very different and needs a fresh question.

Comment: My apologies egreg. At any rate, thanks for the help, my needs have been met.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(edit) 2017: since `xint 1.1 (2014/10/28)` one needs here `\usepackage{xinttools}`. Code updated for that to replace `\usepackage{xint}` of initial answer.*

I am editing this answer because the `1.09f` release of [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) transparently removes all spaces around commas when dealing with comma separated lists. Thus, some of the earlier issues mentioned here are now irrelevant and have been removed.

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{xinttools}     % for \xintFor and \xintFor* loops

% the macro \chisum is also written using an \xintFor loop.
% the math mode dollar signs are in the tabular not in this \chisum

\newcounter{ct}
\def\chisum#1{\def\chisep{\def\chisep{\oplus}}%
              \setcounter{ct}{0}%
              \xintFor ##1 in {#1}\do % #1 is a comma separated list
                  {\stepcounter{ct}%
                   \ifcase ##1
                           \or   \chisep    \chi_{\thect}
                           \else \chisep ##1\chi_{\thect}
                   \fi}%
              }% end of \chisum definition

\newcounter{rowindex}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

% ADDED REMARK: since xint 1.09f, spaces around commas are transparently removed. 
% This is made a bit extreme here for demonstrative purposes.

\def\decompgirreps{ {    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} , {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
  ,{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} ,
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{1,0,0
    ,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, {
           0,0,0, 0 ,0   ,0,0,0,0,0,1},
         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1
                 }}

\setcounter{rowindex}{0}
\begin{tabular}{| c || c | }
    \hline $G^4$ Irreps & Decomp into $SL_2^7$ Irreps \\ \hline \hline
\xintFor #1 in \decompgirreps\do {%
   \stepcounter{rowindex}
   $\mu_{\arabic{rowindex}}$ & $\chisum{#1}$%
   \\ \hline
}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: clebsch coeffs]

---

Here is with the original data provided by the researchers:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{xinttools}     % for \xintFor*

% The original \clebschdata

\def\clebschdata {{{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}},{{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1}},{{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}},{{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,2},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,3,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,3}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,3,0},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,3,0},{0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,3}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,3},{0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,3},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,3,0}}}


% the macro \chisum in its original style with some modifications to let it work

\makeatletter
\newcounter{ct}
\def\chisum#1{$\def\zzsep{\def\zzsep{\oplus}}\setcounter{ct}{0}%
              \@for\tmp:=#1\do
              {\stepcounter{ct}\expandafter\zzz\tmp\relax}$}
\makeatother
% auxiliary macro for the original \chisum
\def\zzz#1\relax{
    \ifnum #1=1
    \zzsep\chi_{\thect}
    \else
    \ifnum #1=0
    \else
    \zzsep#1\chi_{\thect}
    \fi
    \fi
}

\newcounter{rowindex}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{rowindex}{0}
\begin{tabular}{*{12}c}
$\bigotimes$&$\chi_1$&$\chi_2$&$\chi_3$&$\chi_4$&$\chi_5$&$\chi_6$&$\chi_7$&$\chi_8$&$\chi_9$&$\chi_{10}$&$\chi_{11}$ \\
\xintFor #1 in \clebschdata \do {%
   \stepcounter{rowindex}
   $\chi_{\arabic{rowindex}}$ \xintFor #2 in {#1} \do {&\chisum{#2}}%
   \\
}%  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The image is shown much reduced but if you dragged the image to your desktop it has correct size.

> [image: clebsh coeffs]

---

This is my first answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xint}     % for \xintFor* (needs xint v1.09c)

\usepackage{xintexpr} 
% only used because I didn't know what to do with \chisum

%% \usepackage{array} % (not needed here)

% This was the hardest part, generating this:
\def\clebschdata {{{2,1,7,2,9,5,6,0,3,0,2},{1,7,1,1,9,5,1,2,5,8,1},{6,6,1,9,4,1,5,7,3,1,9},{1,9,9,1,4,0,6,7,8,6,5},{2,5,5,5,9,5,2,7,3,7,3},{2,5,8,9,0,5,7,7,4,0,0},{5,5,2,9,2,3,9,8,1,7,5},{7,0,3,0,4,1,0,8,1,8,9},{9,6,6,3,6,6,7,2,5,9,5},{0,4,4,8,1,5,0,1,6,9,9},{2,7,2,7,4,6,4,8,2,5,9}},{{3,4,6,0,0,0,1,0,5,6,5},{4,2,6,4,0,3,0,0,0,5,8},{1,0,9,8,4,5,2,1,6,5,0},{3,1,9,6,0,4,1,4,8,6,9},{0,7,6,7,5,7,8,2,2,8,1},{7,7,9,9,2,2,1,6,8,0,2},{5,4,9,7,8,9,5,7,1,9,2},{4,1,4,0,2,3,8,4,2,6,4},{5,5,8,2,7,7,1,3,1,1,3},{4,5,5,0,7,0,5,2,4,2,2},{1,2,4,0,0,2,8,8,7,8,8}},{{3,2,1,6,8,2,0,1,5,8,8},{3,3,5,7,6,9,2,5,1,0,8},{7,3,5,8,4,6,7,3,0,8,8},{0,9,8,0,4,7,1,5,7,0,1},{9,8,4,5,3,9,2,5,9,3,6},{3,6,0,9,1,4,9,6,5,9,2},{6,4,9,9,8,5,0,3,2,3,1},{2,5,9,5,7,4,9,1,7,6,7},{7,7,1,9,2,7,6,6,2,0,4},{7,2,2,7,4,5,6,0,2,1,4},{1,2,5,9,7,5,1,0,0,8,1}},{{1,7,7,6,9,2,8,6,3,0,5},{4,4,6,4,7,7,3,1,0,7,4},{6,7,9,9,5,5,6,2,5,2,0},{9,1,0,7,3,9,7,5,5,9,3},{8,6,5,0,0,9,0,6,8,6,5},{7,6,6,2,5,7,5,4,9,8,7},{7,6,1,7,1,4,4,1,6,5,2},{4,3,2,6,8,9,4,2,9,2,9},{0,8,8,3,7,9,7,9,1,8,6},{1,0,9,9,8,6,0,8,8,8,5},{5,2,3,6,0,4,9,2,3,4,8}},{{8,7,0,3,7,9,8,2,7,0,7},{9,1,8,7,8,7,0,8,9,0,4},{8,9,3,5,5,3,3,2,8,9,8},{9,7,6,9,1,4,5,4,3,3,0},{9,4,4,3,7,3,0,2,9,9,8},{8,2,0,1,9,4,0,5,1,6,6},{4,9,3,5,1,1,0,6,7,2,8},{4,1,5,7,1,4,3,1,0,8,7},{0,0,6,2,8,6,4,2,8,7,0},{9,7,8,5,3,4,5,7,5,3,5},{7,9,0,3,8,1,9,4,0,1,6}},{{4,4,6,8,4,7,1,0,0,6,7},{0,9,0,4,5,7,6,5,9,0,5},{3,6,8,9,9,7,5,1,7,1,2},{4,7,9,5,2,9,4,8,6,3,4},{4,1,8,6,3,7,4,1,2,1,7},{4,8,9,3,0,2,5,0,5,7,6},{6,9,6,1,9,1,1,6,3,7,8},{1,7,1,8,2,9,0,5,1,4,0},{0,7,9,9,4,5,0,5,9,7,8},{2,7,0,4,3,9,6,9,7,8,2},{8,8,0,4,8,7,4,1,8,3,3}},{{8,0,5,8,4,2,6,8,0,8,0},{0,8,5,9,3,2,1,3,4,7,4},{4,4,0,4,7,2,6,2,6,7,4},{1,0,9,4,2,2,5,9,9,4,4},{7,0,7,6,0,1,8,2,4,2,9},{6,9,5,8,9,1,8,1,0,0,3},{3,6,3,3,2,7,4,0,4,9,5},{5,1,8,4,9,8,3,0,0,7,2},{7,2,5,3,5,1,7,4,0,6,5},{3,9,9,9,8,9,4,3,4,5,7},{3,5,9,6,9,9,9,4,1,8,9}},{{0,1,5,4,7,8,3,4,9,6,8},{0,3,9,5,8,5,1,3,0,9,2},{3,2,4,2,1,7,7,1,8,2,2},{0,0,7,7,8,3,1,9,7,4,5},{0,2,1,0,4,2,8,0,7,5,8},{5,9,7,6,1,5,7,3,5,4,4},{1,7,2,2,8,6,8,8,6,5,4},{4,9,2,9,4,7,5,7,7,8,7},{5,9,9,7,1,1,2,1,1,6,7},{8,3,1,7,9,8,4,1,1,6,6},{4,2,3,0,7,4,8,9,1,2,6}},{{4,1,5,3,2,6,9,1,1,9,0},{1,9,5,2,8,4,2,9,8,0,1},{5,4,6,0,7,4,0,6,3,6,3},{9,0,8,5,0,3,4,0,7,3,5},{0,0,1,4,9,6,7,6,8,7,4},{0,4,2,5,0,8,2,3,2,2,2},{8,0,7,2,3,3,7,9,5,2,7},{7,2,5,4,3,9,7,8,5,8,7},{4,0,2,4,8,9,9,1,8,8,2},{2,3,0,7,1,3,6,9,4,5,5},{3,5,2,2,6,8,9,2,5,3,2}},{{0,0,4,4,3,7,4,7,9,0,8},{9,2,6,0,2,4,4,0,6,1,3},{4,9,9,0,9,3,1,3,4,2,3},{3,7,4,2,4,5,0,1,2,2,3},{8,2,8,5,5,8,3,4,7,5,6},{7,3,1,0,5,7,0,7,0,9,1},{1,6,2,0,2,0,8,1,3,8,9},{0,0,1,3,9,1,1,1,4,4,7},{6,3,9,5,0,7,6,5,1,1,2},{9,6,2,0,1,7,2,9,2,0,8},{1,2,1,2,9,1,0,9,5,1,0}},{{6,4,4,6,6,7,1,0,1,0,2},{3,0,8,5,4,5,6,6,9,0,5},{5,6,2,6,9,7,0,0,1,1,7},{9,8,0,5,9,4,8,3,3,5,0},{6,4,8,8,9,3,2,7,1,5,8},{4,2,8,5,6,8,9,1,2,9,9},{3,7,1,3,5,7,1,2,9,0,2},{1,4,6,5,4,2,4,6,4,2,0},{9,6,1,8,0,5,9,8,3,5,5},{3,1,5,2,8,9,9,3,2,9,0},{9,5,4,2,3,4,0,9,4,6,3}}}


\def\chisum #1{\xintthenumexpr sum(#1)\relax}

\newcounter{rowindex}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{rowindex}{0}
\begin{tabular}{*{12}c}
$\bigotimes$&$\chi_1$&$\chi_2$&$\chi_3$&$\chi_4$&$\chi_5$&$\chi_6$&$\chi_7$&$\chi_8$&$\chi_9$&$\chi_{10}$&$\chi_{11}$ \\
\xintFor #1 in \clebschdata \do {%
   \stepcounter{rowindex}
   $\chi_{\arabic{rowindex}}$ \xintFor #2 in {#1} \do {&\chisum{#2}}%
   \\
}%  
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image: looping in table]

---

### Some info on `\xintFor`.

This is a utility from [xint](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) (version `1.09c` and later). It is not completely expandable but has some properties of completely expandable macros: nesting, capacity to handle group closing contexts such as inside tabulars (LaTeX) or general alignments. Two forms (the spaces before and after `in`,  before and after `\do`, before the `#1`, are optional):

```
\xintFor  #1 in {a,b,c} \do {stuff with #1=a then b then c}
\xintFor* #1 in {{a}{b}{c}} \do {stuff with #1=a then b then c}
```

In the first form, spaces at the start of the list, around commas, and at the end are transparently removed since release `1.09f`.

In the second form, spaces separating braced items do not count. Spaces inside each individual braced item are significant.

One can write `\xintFor #1 in \Tmp \do {stuff}` or equivalently `\xintFor #1 in {\Tmp} \do {stuff}`. But `\Tmp` must expand in *one step* to a comma separated list.

With `\xintFor*` it is slightly different, `\Tmp` is expanded again and again until hitting a brace or something unexpandable at the beginning. So `\def\x{{a}{b}{c}}\def\y{\x}\xintFor* #1 in \y \do {stuff}` is ok, as  `\y` is expanded to `\x` then to `{a}{b}{c}`.  One can also have `\def\x {{a} {b} {c}}`, `\def\y {{d} {e) {f)}` and then `\xintFor* #1 in {\x\y} \do {...}` is like `\xintFor* #1 in {{a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}} \do {...}`.

Comment: Bravo! A very complete answer to my question. Much appreciation jfbu

Comment: The spaces in the data were no problem to remove, so your implementation of `\chisum` worked just fine.

Comment: Ooooh! They look like towers; the leftmost looks kinda like a baroque tower, and then they go to a more middle-eastern design, then what looks like a pagoda. And the last one looks like a birthday cake. Awesome!

Comment: @morbusg do you think there is some hidden mystic message in `SL(2,F_7)` :) ?

Comment: @jfbu: as a consumer of the table, that's the information I'm taking with me from it ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have no hope to get such a gigantic table in a normal document: even in landscape mode and `\tiny` size the overfull is 500pt, that is about 17cm or 7in.

However, here's a general solution that works for any number of components, here I give an example with four. I add also the definition for `\chisum` already discussed. No problem with spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\chisum}{m} % a homage to John Wayne
 {
  \aentropy_chisum:n { #1 }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
\int_new:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_chisum:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
  \int_zero:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
    \aentropy_add_summand:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_aentropy_chisum_seq { \oplus }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \aentropy_add_summand:n #1
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 0 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
     {
      \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 1 } { #1 }
      \exp_not:n { \chi }
      \c_math_subscript_token
      { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int } }
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\clebschtable}{mm}
 {
  \aentropy_clebschtable:no { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
\int_new:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_clebschtable:nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
  \int_zero:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int
  \aentropy_make_first_row:n { #1 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
     {
      \chi
      \c_math_subscript_token
      { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int } }
     }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { ##1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { & \aentropy_chisum:n { ####1 } }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { \\ }
   }
  \begin{array}{l|*{#1}{c}}%| % to keep emacs happy
  \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
  \end{array}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \aentropy_clebschtable:nn { no }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_make_first_row:n #1
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { \bigotimes }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
     {
      & \chi
      \c_math_subscript_token
      { ##1 }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { \\ \hline }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\chisum{5,2,7,8,2,0,0,1,3}$

\bigskip

\def\clebschdata {
 {
  {1,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0},
  {0,2,0,1},
 },
 {
  {0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0},
  {1,0,0,3},
  {0,0,0,1},
 },
 {
  {0,0,1,1},
  {1,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,3,0},
 },
 {
  {0,0,0,1},
  {4,0,0,1},
  {0,2,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0},
 }
}

$\clebschtable{4}{\clebschdata}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for the record, here's the gigantic table all in one PNG

[image]

---

With line breaks; when an optional argument is specified, the macros assume the cells are huge, so they are typeset in `\scriptsize` in the stated width; the column and row headers are still in normal size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,array,pdflscape}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\scriptsize\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\chisum}{m} % a homage to John Wayne
 {
  \aentropy_chisum:n { #1 }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
\int_new:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_chisum:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
  \int_zero:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
    \aentropy_add_summand:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_aentropy_chisum_seq { \oplus }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \aentropy_add_summand:n #1
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 0 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
     {
      \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 1 } { #1 }
      \exp_not:n { \chi }
      \c_math_subscript_token
      { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int } }
     }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\clebschtable}{omm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   { \aentropy_clebschtable:nno { } { #2 } { #3 } }
   { \aentropy_clebschtable:nno { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
\int_new:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_clebschtable:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
  \int_zero:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int
  \aentropy_make_first_row:n { #2 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #3 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
     {
      \chi
      \c_math_subscript_token
      { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_aentropy_clebschtable_row_int } }
     }
    \clist_map_inline:nn { ##1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { & \aentropy_chisum:n { ####1 } }
     }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { \\ }
   }
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
   { \begin{array}{l|*{#2}{c}} }%| % to keep emacs happy
   { \begin{array}{l|*{#2}{C{#1}}} }%| % to keep emacs happy
  \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
  \end{array}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \aentropy_clebschtable:nnn { nno }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_make_first_row:n #1
 {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { \bigotimes }
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl
     {
      &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}
       {
        \chi
        \c_math_subscript_token
        { ##1 }
       }
     }
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_clebschtable_tl { \\ \hline }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% $\chisum{5,2,7,8,2,0,0,1,3}$

% \bigskip

\def\clebschdata {
 {
  {1,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0},
  {0,2,0,1},
 },
 {
  {0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0},
  {1,0,0,3},
  {0,0,0,1},
 },
 {
  {0,0,1,1},
  {1,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,3,0},
 },
 {
  {0,0,0,1},
  {4,0,0,1},
  {0,2,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0},
 }
}

$\clebschtable{4}{\clebschdata}$

\def\clebschdata {{{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}},{{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1}},{{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}},{{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,1,0,0,2},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,3,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,3}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,3,0},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,3,0},{0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,3}},{{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1},{0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,2},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,2,0},{0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,0,3},{0,0,0,2,2,0,2,2,0,0,3},{1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,3,3,0}}}

\begin{landscape}
\centering
$\clebschtable[1.8cm]{11}{\clebschdata}$
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, your table looks nice. I am inclined to use jfbu's answer however since I don't have LaTeX 3.

Also I have indeed managed to get the whole table to fit on one page, it involved using landscape, small text, and line wrapping :-)

Comment: Your updated table looks very nice, if I can manage to get LaTeX 3 installed I will use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Thanks to jfbu for the data

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape,array}
\makeatletter
\def\clebstable#1{%
\begin{tabular}{l*{12}{>{\centering}p{1.5cm}}}%
$\bigotimes$&$\chi_1$&$\chi_2$&$\chi_3$&$\chi_4$&$\chi_5$&$\chi_6$&$\chi_7$&$\chi_8$&$\chi_9$&$\chi_{10}$&$\chi_{11}$ \tabularnewline
\clebA1#1\relax
\end{tabular}}

\def\clebA#1#2#3{%
  $\chi_{#1}$\clebB#2\relax
  \ifx\relax#3\else\tabularnewline\expandafter\clebA\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}\fi}

\def\clebB#1#2{%
  &$\gdef\clebD{\gdef\clebD{\oplus}}\clebC1#1,$%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\expandafter\clebB\fi}

\def\clebC#1#2,{%
 \ifnum#2=\z@\else
  \clebD
  \ifnum#2=\@ne\else#2\fi
  \chi_{#1}%
 \fi
 \ifnum#1<11 \expandafter\clebC\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\expandafter}\fi}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}\tiny
\clebstable {{{2,1,7,2,9,5,6,0,3,0,2},{1,7,1,1,9,5,1,2,5,8,1},{6,6,1,9,4,1,5,7,3,1,9},{1,9,9,1,4,0,6,7,8,6,5},{2,5,5,5,9,5,2,7,3,7,3},{2,5,8,9,0,5,7,7,4,0,0},{5,5,2,9,2,3,9,8,1,7,5},{7,0,3,0,4,1,0,8,1,8,9},{9,6,6,3,6,6,7,2,5,9,5},{0,4,4,8,1,5,0,1,6,9,9},{2,7,2,7,4,6,4,8,2,5,9}},{{3,4,6,0,0,0,1,0,5,6,5},{4,2,6,4,0,3,0,0,0,5,8},{1,0,9,8,4,5,2,1,6,5,0},{3,1,9,6,0,4,1,4,8,6,9},{0,7,6,7,5,7,8,2,2,8,1},{7,7,9,9,2,2,1,6,8,0,2},{5,4,9,7,8,9,5,7,1,9,2},{4,1,4,0,2,3,8,4,2,6,4},{5,5,8,2,7,7,1,3,1,1,3},{4,5,5,0,7,0,5,2,4,2,2},{1,2,4,0,0,2,8,8,7,8,8}},{{3,2,1,6,8,2,0,1,5,8,8},{3,3,5,7,6,9,2,5,1,0,8},{7,3,5,8,4,6,7,3,0,8,8},{0,9,8,0,4,7,1,5,7,0,1},{9,8,4,5,3,9,2,5,9,3,6},{3,6,0,9,1,4,9,6,5,9,2},{6,4,9,9,8,5,0,3,2,3,1},{2,5,9,5,7,4,9,1,7,6,7},{7,7,1,9,2,7,6,6,2,0,4},{7,2,2,7,4,5,6,0,2,1,4},{1,2,5,9,7,5,1,0,0,8,1}},{{1,7,7,6,9,2,8,6,3,0,5},{4,4,6,4,7,7,3,1,0,7,4},{6,7,9,9,5,5,6,2,5,2,0},{9,1,0,7,3,9,7,5,5,9,3},{8,6,5,0,0,9,0,6,8,6,5},{7,6,6,2,5,7,5,4,9,8,7},{7,6,1,7,1,4,4,1,6,5,2},{4,3,2,6,8,9,4,2,9,2,9},{0,8,8,3,7,9,7,9,1,8,6},{1,0,9,9,8,6,0,8,8,8,5},{5,2,3,6,0,4,9,2,3,4,8}},{{8,7,0,3,7,9,8,2,7,0,7},{9,1,8,7,8,7,0,8,9,0,4},{8,9,3,5,5,3,3,2,8,9,8},{9,7,6,9,1,4,5,4,3,3,0},{9,4,4,3,7,3,0,2,9,9,8},{8,2,0,1,9,4,0,5,1,6,6},{4,9,3,5,1,1,0,6,7,2,8},{4,1,5,7,1,4,3,1,0,8,7},{0,0,6,2,8,6,4,2,8,7,0},{9,7,8,5,3,4,5,7,5,3,5},{7,9,0,3,8,1,9,4,0,1,6}},{{4,4,6,8,4,7,1,0,0,6,7},{0,9,0,4,5,7,6,5,9,0,5},{3,6,8,9,9,7,5,1,7,1,2},{4,7,9,5,2,9,4,8,6,3,4},{4,1,8,6,3,7,4,1,2,1,7},{4,8,9,3,0,2,5,0,5,7,6},{6,9,6,1,9,1,1,6,3,7,8},{1,7,1,8,2,9,0,5,1,4,0},{0,7,9,9,4,5,0,5,9,7,8},{2,7,0,4,3,9,6,9,7,8,2},{8,8,0,4,8,7,4,1,8,3,3}},{{8,0,5,8,4,2,6,8,0,8,0},{0,8,5,9,3,2,1,3,4,7,4},{4,4,0,4,7,2,6,2,6,7,4},{1,0,9,4,2,2,5,9,9,4,4},{7,0,7,6,0,1,8,2,4,2,9},{6,9,5,8,9,1,8,1,0,0,3},{3,6,3,3,2,7,4,0,4,9,5},{5,1,8,4,9,8,3,0,0,7,2},{7,2,5,3,5,1,7,4,0,6,5},{3,9,9,9,8,9,4,3,4,5,7},{3,5,9,6,9,9,9,4,1,8,9}},{{0,1,5,4,7,8,3,4,9,6,8},{0,3,9,5,8,5,1,3,0,9,2},{3,2,4,2,1,7,7,1,8,2,2},{0,0,7,7,8,3,1,9,7,4,5},{0,2,1,0,4,2,8,0,7,5,8},{5,9,7,6,1,5,7,3,5,4,4},{1,7,2,2,8,6,8,8,6,5,4},{4,9,2,9,4,7,5,7,7,8,7},{5,9,9,7,1,1,2,1,1,6,7},{8,3,1,7,9,8,4,1,1,6,6},{4,2,3,0,7,4,8,9,1,2,6}},{{4,1,5,3,2,6,9,1,1,9,0},{1,9,5,2,8,4,2,9,8,0,1},{5,4,6,0,7,4,0,6,3,6,3},{9,0,8,5,0,3,4,0,7,3,5},{0,0,1,4,9,6,7,6,8,7,4},{0,4,2,5,0,8,2,3,2,2,2},{8,0,7,2,3,3,7,9,5,2,7},{7,2,5,4,3,9,7,8,5,8,7},{4,0,2,4,8,9,9,1,8,8,2},{2,3,0,7,1,3,6,9,4,5,5},{3,5,2,2,6,8,9,2,5,3,2}},{{0,0,4,4,3,7,4,7,9,0,8},{9,2,6,0,2,4,4,0,6,1,3},{4,9,9,0,9,3,1,3,4,2,3},{3,7,4,2,4,5,0,1,2,2,3},{8,2,8,5,5,8,3,4,7,5,6},{7,3,1,0,5,7,0,7,0,9,1},{1,6,2,0,2,0,8,1,3,8,9},{0,0,1,3,9,1,1,1,4,4,7},{6,3,9,5,0,7,6,5,1,1,2},{9,6,2,0,1,7,2,9,2,0,8},{1,2,1,2,9,1,0,9,5,1,0}},{{6,4,4,6,6,7,1,0,1,0,2},{3,0,8,5,4,5,6,6,9,0,5},{5,6,2,6,9,7,0,0,1,1,7},{9,8,0,5,9,4,8,3,3,5,0},{6,4,8,8,9,3,2,7,1,5,8},{4,2,8,5,6,8,9,1,2,9,9},{3,7,1,3,5,7,1,2,9,0,2},{1,4,6,5,4,2,4,6,4,2,0},{9,6,1,8,0,5,9,8,3,5,5},{3,1,5,2,8,9,9,3,2,9,0},{9,5,4,2,3,4,0,9,4,6,3}}}

\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am flattered that you use my `11x11x11` list rather than the actual Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, as added in an edit by the OP to his original question! perhaps there is an underlying group (of a new kind) with these decomposition coefficients (they were obtained as the digits of `1234/56789` after the decimal mark) ;-)

Comment: @jfbu ah I didn't notice the OP edit (I'd done most of this earlier, but left off to eat and just posted the rest without checking for updates:-)